# Does PyTorch support variable with dynamic dimension?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, dynamic-variables

I've updated my question based upon the variable dimension of variables.

Suppose the input tensor stores the 3d points with dimension 10x3, 10 means the #points and 3 is the feature dimension (say x,y,z coordinates). The dimension of the variable depends on the input tensor, say its dimension is 10x10. When the input tensor changes its dimension to 50x3, then the dimension of the variable will also have to change to 50x50.

I know in Tensorflow, if the input dimension is changing/unknown, we can declare it as tf.placeholder(None,3). However, I never meet the situation where the size of variable is changing/unknown, it seems that the variable will always have the fixed dimension.

I am currently learning PyTorch and don't know whether PyTorch supports this function. Any information would be appreciated!

========= Original question ========

I have a variable in which the size is changeable when input dimension changes. For example, if input is 10x2, then the variable should be 10x10. If input is 25x2, then the variable should be 25x25. As my understanding, the variable is used to store weights, which normally has fixed dimension. However in my case, the dimension of the variable depends on input data, which can change. Does PyTorch currently supports this kind of function?

Thanks!

Comment: Giving more context on the input variables can help to narrow down the ambiguity of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is little ambiguous. When you say, your input is say, `10x2`, you need to define what the input tensor contains.

I am assuming you are talking about `torch.autograd.Variable`. If you want to use PyTorch's functionality, what you need to do is to provide your input through a tensor in the desired shape of the target function.

For example, if you want to use [RNN](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html?highlight=rnn#torch.nn.RNN) implemented in PyTorch for an input sentence of length 10 where each word is represented by a 300 dimensional vector (e.g., word embedding), then you can do as follows.

```
rnn = nn.RNN(300, 256, 2) # emb_size=300,hidden_size=256,num_layers=2
input = Variable(torch.randn(10, 1, 300)) # sent_length=10,batch_size=1,emb_size=300
h0 = Variable(torch.randn(2, 1, 256)) # num_layers=2,batch_size=1,hidden_size=256
output, hn = rnn(input, h0)
```

If you have more than 1 sentence, then you can provide them in batch. In that case, you need to pad them to handle variable lengths. As you can see, RNN doesn't care about the sentence length, it can handle variable lengths but to provide many sentences in batch, you need padding. You can explore related functionalities in the [official documentation](http://pytorch.org/docs/0.2.0/).

---

Since you didn't mention what is your input actually, I am assuming you need variables with variable number of timesteps, in that case PyTorch can serve your purpose. Actually, PyTorch is developed to meet all basic functionalities that are required to build deep neural network architectures.

Comment: Hi Wasi, thanks for the comment! Actually the input tensor is the 3d points, instead of timesteps. I've updated my question and please check the details in the question. Thanks!